# How to specify a keyboard language in Android Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I'm coding an app in Android Compose.
I have a TextField with text in known language, say German.
When a user taps the TextField, the keyboard pops up.
I want the keyboard to pop up preset with German language (given it is present on the phone) to save the user few taps.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an API now for this feature.
This is the signature for TextField,

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TextField(
    value: TextFieldValue,
    onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions(),
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape =
        MaterialTheme.shapes.small.copy(bottomEnd = ZeroCornerSize, bottomStart = ZeroCornerSize),
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors()
)
```

The parameter related to Keyboard is keyboardOptions, and if you check the code for KeyboardOptions

```kotlin
class KeyboardOptions constructor(
    val capitalization: KeyboardCapitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
    val autoCorrect: Boolean = true,
    val keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    val imeAction: ImeAction = ImeAction.Default
)

inline class KeyboardType internal constructor(@Suppress("unused") private val value: Int) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return when (this) {
            Text -> "Text"
            Ascii -> "Ascii"
            Number -> "Number"
            Phone -> "Phone"
            Uri -> "Uri"
            Email -> "Email"
            Password -> "Password"
            NumberPassword -> "NumberPassword"
            else -> "Invalid"
        }
    }
...
inline class ImeAction internal constructor(@Suppress("unused") private val value: Int) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return when (this) {
            None -> "None"
            Default -> "Default"
            Go -> "Go"
            Search -> "Search"
            Send -> "Send"
            Previous -> "Previous"
            Next -> "Next"
            Done -> "Done"
            else -> "Invalid"
        }
    }
...
```

You can only change the keyboard type and the action button, but there is no API to change the language at this time.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I could not find as well.